# Handling items in queue when other end fails to receive

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, message-queue

I am developing a plugin for a system, the plugin catches some events in that system, wraps them into eatable format and pushes out to another system for analysis. The overhead generated by the plugin must be as low as possible. So what I have so far is that I catch the event and push it into a blockingQueue and another thread is listening, if the queue gets an item it will try to push it out from the system. Code I have:

```
@Override
public void start(){
    StatsManager statsManager = new StatsManager();
}

//catch event
public void taskFinished(){
    statsManager.pushData(Context.getData());
}
```

The StatsManager:

```
private BlockingQueue<MyItem> blockingQueue;

public StatsManager(){
    blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<MyItem>(32768);
    SenderThread sender = new SenderThread(blockingQueue);
    new Thread(sender).start();
}

public void pushData(MyItem item){
    try {
        blockingQueue.put(item);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.error(e.toString());
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}


private class SenderThread implements Runnable{

    private BlockingQueue<MyItem> blockingQueue;

    public SenderThread(BlockingQueue<MyItem> queue){
        blockingQueue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true){
            try {
                MyItem item = blockingQueue.take();
                postItem(item);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                logger.error(e.toString());
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
```

The question is - how to handle situation where sending item to another end fails? I have tried that it is possible to put items back to a queue, but that would cause the while loop go berzerk and constantly try to send. Would it make sense to try to understand from exception what troubles the system and somehow intelligently increase value of thread.Sleep()?

I am also considering writing the data down somehow, but I am trying to understand if I really need it? I am pretty unexperienced with this stuff, so please point out what other horrible issues I don't foresee.

If it is relevant, I am estimating 50000 items being pushed in 24h period.

Comment: Usually you have a unique identifier in the message and you will have a request and response queue , based on the response and the unique identifier and a lets say status you can implement a correct workflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should certainly inspect the reason for the error and decide intelligently how to deal with the issue.

You may also need to base your decision partly on the nature of the message too.

Putting them back in the main queue would be a mistake. I would recommend holding an inner queue of failed messages that are awaiting resend. You could then `poll` both queues in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

you could also move the failed `MyItem`s to another `failedItemQueue` and associated thread where you do all the error reporting and perform delayed resend attempts, maybe using `Thread.sleep`.